# Angular2 not updating templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, angular

In the Visual Studio 2015 (udpate 3) I am using Angular2 and when I change something in the template, for example I can delete all, nothing is happenning. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not.

In the beginning of the project, it worked. Once I reinstalled Visual Studio (from update 2 to 3), it was working for a week and now it is the same. This bug has cost really a lot of time. Before the total reinstalling sometimes helped clean and rebuild or restart of VS, now any of these things don´t help.

Any idea?

Comment: Please post a more detailed question, try to post a screenshoot of your console showing errors etc. Its almost impossible to help you out now without knowing anything more.

Comment: It seems a browser cache problem but yes, we need more information about your questions. standy by.